# Adwords Remarketing tag on a Drupal 7 site

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

We are trying to put a google adwords remarketing tag on our site.
www.firstcom.dk. (CMS Drupal 7)

But every time i try to insert the code somewhere drupal changes the code so it do not work probably.

When i use Chrome addon (Google Tags addon) it says.:

Remarketing Tag (new) 1014770152  Minor Issues
Conversion ID
1014770152
Conversion Label
IrCRCMj-zgMQ6NPw4wM
 tag found.
Warning: Missing CDATA comments. more info

And referre to this link.:
https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/2978937?ref_topic=2947092#cdata_comments

And google is right. Drupal Change this.:

`/* <![CDATA[ */`

To this

```
/ <![CDATA[ /
```

My problem is that i can't find were to paste this code on my site... :-(
Can any one help?

Best regards 
Kent Ellegaard

Answer (score 0):

To add this code to page you could use block with PHP input format (which will not change code of your snippet for sure). I think this change was done by some of your input formats if you're using block/node or similar to add this snippet. If you add this snippet directly to code then you need to check your editor settings.